# signInSuccessUrl of firebaseUI not work for me

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I followed this tutorial [enter link description here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/authenticating-a-vue-js-application-with-firebase-ui-8870a3a5cff8)

After authentication succeed (Has been confirmed in Firebase console), the page not move to "/success"(signInSuccessUrl), and show the error message below:

[image]

I tried to changed the url to other page, "https://google.com", but it also not work.

Any advice will be helpful.

main.js

```
    new Vue({
        vuetify,
        el: '#app',
        router,
        components: { App },
        template: '<App/>',
        created() {
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                if (user) {
                    console.log("success")
                    this.$router.push('/success')
                } else {
                    console.log("auth")
                    // this.$router.push('/auth')
                }
            });
        },
    })
```

router/index.js

```
    let router = new Router({
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          component: Auth
        },
        {
          path: '/auth',
          component: Auth
        },
        {
          path: '/success',
          component: AuthSuccess
        }
      ]
    })
    
    export default router;
```

Auth.vue

```
<template lang="html">
  <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
</template>
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
import firebaseui from "firebaseui-ja";
import "firebaseui-ja/dist/firebaseui.css";

export default {
  name: "auth",
  mounted() {
    var uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: "/success",
      signInOptions: [firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID],
    };
    console.log("auth start");
    var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
    console.log("ui start")
  },
};
</script>
```

Success.vue

```
<template> 
  <div> 
    <h1>Signup succeeded</h1> 
    <button @click='logOut'>Log out</button> 
    <hr> 
    <img :src="photo" style="height: 120px"> <br> 
    <p>{{name}}</p> 
    <p>{{email}}</p> 
    <p>{{userId}}</p> 
    <hr> 
    <pre>{{user}}</pre> 
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forget to say I deployed this app to google app engine.

After I add localhost:8080 to the "Authorized JavaScript origins" in "APIs & Service" -> Credentials -> "Client ID for Web application", there is no problem now.

But there is one strange thing left: After I delete localhost:8080, the redirect still works fine.